# ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath() inside ElasticBeanstalk return http instead of https

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a **Spring** **Boot** **Application** on EB using a docker container.
It works well but in some parts of my code I've something like this:

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder builder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath();
```

to get the current url of the application. In the local machine it works fine but on EB (using classing load balancer) - that uses https protocol - that line of code return **http** instead of **https**.

I've already added this configuration in my project:

```
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        bean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
        return bean;
    }
```

Do you have any hint to follow to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this Spring Boot property:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy = framework
```